# How to get an entity as a parameter in rest api post method?

Tags: java, rest, post

I am trying to get a user defined entity as a parameter in my request using rest webservice. I am using post method, but I don't know why my API call is returning 400 as response code.

I have seen the questions already posted here. But my doubt is something related to sending request where I didn't find any answers related to that here.

My code is as follows,

This is my API method which corresponds to the URI I am trying to map,

My method:

```
@POST
@Path("/mobileapplicationAPI/requestWindow/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void mobileAppRequest(Entity entity)
{
    //This function contains logic and returns something.
}
```

Request :

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(parameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    con.connect();
    response_code = con.getResponseCode();
}
```

I am expecting to get the API call correctly but it returns me 400 as response code as I stated earlier.

Comment: What is "parameters" object ?

Comment: Did you try to remove the last "/ " after requestWindow.
And is entity a JSON Object?

Comment: Yes entity is my json object and parameters is also json object in another environment where I make api call.

Comment: can you add `con.setRequestMethod("POST");`?

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning that in my code, I have set that as post method already.